# Library to modify Excel in Python

Tags: python, c#, microsoft-excel, vba

I love to use Python, but I also found C# and VBA as options.

I want to read one Excel file, then search another Excel file (with multiple sheets), and use this information to modify the initial Excel file.

I did some searching but couldn't find anything that works with Python 3.7.2, or Excel 365. I need Python 3.7.2 for school, so I can't downgrade to Python 3.5 (which works with openpyxl), however I am willing to downgrade my Excel version.

Is there any library I could use (preferably Python)?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I've just modified your question a bit to make it on-topic. Asking for [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185) and [languages](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185) is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Pretty much any Python library that works with 3.5 will should with 3.7.2.

Comment: "`so I can't downgrade to Python 3.5 (which works with openpyxl)`" - could you not use a Virtual Machine? Or simply have two paths to Python, one of which (the first installed) you would have to specify the complete path to the  interpreter when invoking it?

Comment: There is no need to downgrade Python or Excel. If you like OpenPyXL, just use it. Note that pandas uses a combination of xlrd, XlsxWriter, and OpenPyXL for handling Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will work in 3.7.2.

https://pandas.pydata.org/

This is a great tool for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to try it, and see if it works.

Comment: It's a great library, but it has lots of dependencies, chief among them being NumPy, which has compiled binary components, which makes it extremely Python version-sensitive. It also depends on other Python libraries to work with Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

[Spire.XLS for Python](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/xls-for-python.html) library is capable of creating, reading, editing, and converting Excel files in Python. It has no dependencies and is easy to use.

Here is a simple code example that shows how to edit an Excel file with it:

```
from spire.xls import *
from spire.common import *    

workbook = Workbook()
#Load an Excel file
workbook.LoadFromFile(inputFile)

#Get the first worksheet
sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]

#Update the text and style of the cell "C1"
sheet.Range["C1"].Text = "Updated text"
sheet.Range["C1"].Style.Font.Size = 15
sheet.Range["C1"].Style.Font.Color = Color.get_DeepSkyBlue()

#Save the result file
workbook.SaveToFile("result.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013)
workbook.Dispose()
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company that developed this library.